# GWT & Angular JS Integration

Tags: gwt, angularjs, integration

For Normal JavaScript It is possible to integrate with GWT with JSNI (JavaScript Native Interface).

Is it possible to integrate AngularJS with GWT ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, yes. No one said it was easy though.

See https://github.com/cromwellian/angulargwt, announced in https://plus.google.com/110412141990454266397/posts/AYmRTDHeAZT and https://plus.google.com/110412141990454266397/posts/G1v6j6Pri5u

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://github.com/FinamTrade/angulargwt
It's a fork of Ray Cromwell's angulargwt with some things fixed

Update: I updated README and uploaded library to maven central

Comment: Can you please explain what things are fixed and how it addresses the integration of AngularJS and GWT. The README there doesn't really help much.

Comment: Sorry for delay.  
* I splitted project into two modules: angulargwt library and TodoMVC showcase app.  
* Bootstrapping has been made easy: just include your angularjs script into your gwt html page.  
* Scope and Model jso implementations generation made simpler.  
* Added NgNativeDepends annotation to include javascript angularjs modules.  
For now you can look at TodoMVC module and play with it. I'm in the process of releasing library to maven central and I am going to update README in couple of days.

Comment: Thank you! I have merged your comment here into the answer.